# How do I get a list of selected items from a list box on my web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, listbox

This is not working:

```
var selectedItems = lbxSourceTables.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
```

How do I go about getting a list of the items selected by a user on my web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var selectedItems = yourListBox.Items.GetSelectedItems();
```

// Use this extensión method

```
public static IEnumerable<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(this ListItemCollection items)
{
    return items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean listbox, then `listBox1.SelectedItems`

Comment: this is ASP .NET. SelectedItems is not a property of listBox